# How to split a ranked page or category?

Tags: url, keywords, ranking, google-ranking

This is a general question and not related to the specified URL.
I have some websites that contain many categories. Now I want to split some categories.

For example:

I have `office table and chair` category with a unique URL and this page is ranked with some keywords about `office chair` and `office table`.

Now I want to split this category into two categories. One for `office table` and one for `office chair`.

**And the question is:**

How can I tell Google that the old category changed to these two categories? and how to change URLs in SERP for related ranked keywords.

Comment: Google prefers pages that either 404 or 301 and to discover new pages naturally. You can 404 the old category page and let Google discover the new category pages. That is the simplest way. Otherwise, I am sure there are options such as linking the new categories in the old category page if there are links to that page. You can always 301 the old category page to a page where all the categories are linked or something helpful. It is up to you.

Comment: If i use 404 for old category, All keyword ranks for old category page will lost.

Comment: No they wont. Your new pages will take it's place.

Comment: All pages deindexed and new pages indexed but has not any rank even in page 10.Maybe need more time?

Comment: Definitely. It often takes week or a couple of months before a page begins to perform where it should.

Comment: Your new categories don't have to replace your old category.   I would suggest creating the new categories but leaving the old mixed category in place.

Comment: @closetnoc After a week, new URLs shows on page 4 in related keywords.Before it, one keyword was in position 1 and another keyword was in position 8. I don't know is it possible to earn previous rank, even for on keyword!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for comment. I feel search engine has not enough reason to change URLs in SERP. But this way can be tested.

Comment: @closetnoc I tested it.After 2 month new URLs are in position 20,21 in SERP. Before delete old URL(return 404) , I had rank 1 for one keyword and rank 4 for another keyword.I lost my ranking with 2 keywords.But URLs changed

Answer (score 3):

There is no way at this point to split your page rank between two new categories the way you are asking about. The only thing I have seen done with this before was to keep the former category online but not in the navigation bar so that Google could still access it but choose which one of the new split categories where the most important and do a 301 redirect to the new split category.

It will take a while to get your ranking on the new categories as high as your former single category but if the quality is the same or better then you should see it balance out and improve at a later date as the keyword analysis and inbound links get established with Google again.